# how to "like" when I already have an auth token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-like

I'm getting into the grimy guts of a problem that has turned out to be rather cumbersome so I turn to you, the experts, for help.

what I've done so far: I am building an iphone app with phonegap.  I am using the provided fbconnect (in phonegap github) code which gives some rather convenient javascript based example code to build things like a comment and check in request. I have comments and checkins fully working how I want, and I have an auth_token that I am successfully toting around.

enter the like button: I understand that you cannot make like requests via xmlhttprequest in the same way that you can with comments for example, so I am stuck using an iframe (unless there is a better alternative).

what I need help with: right now, since the iframe is triggering its own login, I have the situation where the user might log in to like, and then have to log in again to comment which is not a viable.  Is there a way to pass a valid auth token to the iframe so the user wont be prompted to log in again or some other sneaky way to authorize through the childbrowser solution that I have currently implemented and then share the auth token to the rest of the app?

notes:  I havent passed an app ID to my auth implementation but I noticed that the iframe does pass an app ID. would including an app ID in my auth request somehow link the logins so facebook could recognize that the user is already logged in through the app?

I can't think of any specific code to include since this is more of a general question but if there is anything you'd like to have a look at please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, mainly for security and spam prevention.  The only way to have the user like your page is rendering the iframe code in a webview.  This requires a traditional email/password login with Facebook.  Using the graph api is the only way to use things like commenting and checkins, and this requires a user to login via a separate mechanism and then subsequently approve your app.  There is no back door logging in mechanism.

Comment: I've done some experimenting since I posted this question and it looks like when I log in via my oauth call, then the like button suddenly knows who I am. I'm trying to figure out where the streams are crossing but dont have a great reliable idea why.  I tried making the app IDs the same for the oauth and like procedures and it seems to have had that effect, however removing the appID altogether from the like button seems to have worked as well.  maybe its just as simple as facebook knowing I logged in with ui-webkit in both instances.